# Redirect rule Worpdress Images

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect, plugins

I am currently using one of the most popular plugins to perform 301 redirects (Redirection) for WordPress, and I need to create a rule that allows me to make a 301 redirect according to the following example:

https://**[domain]**/portal/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/uploads/**[year]**/**[month]**/**[name_file].jpg.webp**

to

https://[domain]/portal/wp-content/uploads/**[year]**/**[month]**/**[name_file].webp**

I am very grateful in advance to anyone who can assist me.

I want to avoid having large amounts of 404 errors